# Solving tridiagonal Toeplitz system using SIMD instructions

Tags: linear-system, vectorization

I need to solve many small Toeplitz systems that fit entirely in cache, meaning the computation is compute bound. Are there vectorizable algorithms for this?

I found a few older articles: (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702009111) but they parallelise in a strided way, which is not suitable for modern processors, or increase the number of flops to $O(n log n)$ (several examples in https://www.math.uni-kiel.de/scicom/de/absolventinnen-und-absolventen/tim-wichelmann-bachelorarbeit).

Comment: It is critical to know if your systems are independent and can be solved concurrently or if you need to solve them one-by-one.  In the first case, the problems can be solved trivially using SIMD operations. In the second case, we can adapt the Arbenz-Heglund partitioning used by the ScaLAPACK solver for diagonally dominant systems and do a SIMD parallel implementation of single step of cyclic reduction using  a sequential solver to handle the Schur complement.